# Pine Script - Coloring entire plot line based on last bar

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to work out how to change the color of the overall plot based on the color of the most recent bar. currently the plot line is changing color based on the bar in the chart so ive got a patch work color plot rather than a plot that is consistent color?

Answer (score 0):

its not possible to change the color of the entire plot in code.
as you discovered, you can only affect what you plot per candle.

Comment: thanks for confirming my thoughts! I have a feeling this could be the same answer but if it possible to hide/display/any way to toggle a plot based on the last bar?

Comment: not if you're using the `plot` function no. you're essentially trying to use data from the future...not possible.